# parsing weird structure of the HTML using python - second ver

Tags: html, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I asked a question yesterday, it was very clearly understood, but I have more tricky question now.

First, show this html structure what I want to parse

```
<body>
    <div id="links">
        <a href='url1'>apple-explain</a>
        <blackquote>
            <a href='url1'>link-1</a>
        </blackquote>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        <p>apple</p></div>

    <div id="links">
        <a href='batch_url1'>bear-explain</a>
        <blackquote>
            <a href='url2'>link-1</a>
            <a href='url3'>link-2</a>
        </blackquote>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        <p>bear</p></div>

    <div id="links">
        <a href='url4'>cat-explain</a>
        <blackquote>
            <a href='url4'>link-1</a>
        </blackquote>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        <p>cat</p></div>

    <div id="links">
        <a href='batchurl2'>duck-explain</a>
        <blackquote>
            <a href='url5'>link-1</a>
            <a href='url6'>link-2</a>
            <a href='url7'>link-3</a>
        </blackquote>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        <p>duck</p></div>

    <div id="links">
        <a href='url8'>egg-explain</a></div>
        <blackquote>
            <a href='url8'>link-1</a>
        </blackquote>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
        <p>egg</p></div>
    #etc
</body>
```

It seems slightly long, but structure is simple

```
<div id="links">
    <a href=url>some explain</a>
    <blackquote>
        <a href=url>link number</a>
    </blackquote></div>
<div id="info">
    <p>info keyword</p></div>
```

Here my purpose is

to "grab all urls in , delete duplications, and matching them to info keywords".

for example, apple part has two , but they're same href
and bear part, it has 3  and 3 href, one is in the  but two are in the

I want to get cleared tuple and print

tuple is

```
(apple, url1)
(bear, [batch_url1, url2, url3])
etc...
```

printed form is

```
url1 = apple
batch_url1 = bear
url2 = bear
url3 = bear
etc
```

here's my code,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""that HTML""")
url_list = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'links'})
info_list = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'links'})

for url, info in zip(url_list, info_list):
    for temp in url.find_all():
        infokeyword = info.text
        urls = temp.attrs['href']

zipped = zip(infokeyword, urls)
d=len(infokeyword)
for n in range(0, d+1):
    print(str(infokeyword[n]) + " = " + str(urls[n])
```

And when run, the result came like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Users/Hyungsoo/PycharmProjects/untitled1/zx.py", line 59, in <module>
urls = temp.attrs['href']
KeyError: 'href'
```

How can I make like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get distinct `url` you can use [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `set` as **default_factory**.

```
In [72]: from collections import defaultdict

In [73]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [74]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<body>
   ....:     <div id="links">
   ....:         <a href='url1'>apple-explain</a>
   ....:         <blackquote>
   ....:             <a href='url1'>link-1</a>
   ....:         </blackquote>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div id="info">
   ....:         <p>apple</p></div>
   ....: 
   ....:     <div id="links">
   ....:         <a href='batch_url1'>bear-explain</a>
   ....:         <blackquote>
   ....:             <a href='url2'>link-1</a>
   ....:             <a href='url3'>link-2</a>
   ....:         </blackquote>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div id="info">
   ....:         <p>bear</p></div>
   ....: 
   ....:     <div id="links">
   ....:         <a href='url4'>cat-explain</a>
   ....:         <blackquote>
   ....:             <a href='url4'>link-1</a>
   ....:         </blackquote>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div id="info">
   ....:         <p>cat</p></div>
   ....: 
   ....:     <div id="links">
   ....:         <a href='batchurl2'>duck-explain</a>
   ....:         <blackquote>
   ....:             <a href='url5'>link-1</a>
   ....:             <a href='url6'>link-2</a>
   ....:             <a href='url7'>link-3</a>
   ....:         </blackquote>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div id="info">
   ....:         <p>duck</p></div>
   ....: 
   ....:     <div id="links">
   ....:         <a href='url8'>egg-explain</a></div>
   ....:         <blackquote>
   ....:             <a href='url8'>link-1</a>
   ....:         </blackquote>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div id="info">
   ....:         <p>egg</p></div>
   ....:     #etc
   ....: </body>""")

In [75]: distinct_url = defaultdict(set)

In [76]: links = soup.select('div#links')

In [77]: infos = soup.select('div#info p')

In [78]: for k, v in zip(links, infos):
   ....:     for l in k.find_all('a'):
   ....:         distinct_url[v.text].add(l.attrs['href'])
   ....:         

In [79]: distinct_url
Out[79]: defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'apple': {'url1'}, 'duck': {'url5', 'url7', 'url6', 'batchurl2'}, 'bear': {'batch_url1', 'url3', 'url2'}, 'cat': {'url4'}, 'egg': {'url8'}})

In [80]: for info, lks in distinct_url.items():
   ....:     for lk in lks:
   ....:         print(info, lk)
   ....:         
apple url1
duck url5
duck url7
duck url6
duck batchurl2
bear batch_url1
bear url3
bear url2
cat url4
egg url8
```